# PHP MIDI Generator

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there away to program a software that generates MIDI from text ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to perform?
Are you looking for existing converter or do you wan to program one itself?

Answer (score 5):

A quick google search returned this...

http://valentin.dasdeck.com/php/midi/

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1362-PHP-Read-write-and-manipulate-MIDI-files-and-data.html

Comment: Those 2 are the exact same thing, and right now it doesn't help me a lot since it won't generate a valid midi file even from its own example. That's how I got here...